# как отслеживать gif в pyrogram

Tags: python, бот, pyrogram

У меня есть группа в телеграмме и мне нужно как-то отслеживать гифки которые присылают люди, зайдя в документацию я не нашел там информации, полазив в интернете тоже, попытался получить через message, но гифки бот даже не воспринимает, можно ли как-то отслеживать гифки когда их кто-то присылает в чат?

Answer (score 0):

```
Client.send_animation(chat_id (int | str), animation (str | BinaryIO), caption (str, optional))
```

> Отправка анимационных файлов (анимация или видео H.264/MPEG-4 AVC без
> звука)

*Сыль:* https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_animation

Answer (score 0):

Наверное запоздало, но может кому поможет))

```
@app.on_message(filters=filters.animation)
```